# Installing h5py mpi in Windows with Visual Studio

Tags: pip, mpi, h5py, cl

I've been trying to install h5py but I've got a problem with the setup. I'm  trying to follow the guide explained http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/build.html#custom-installation 
I first set on Powershell:

```
$env:HDF5_MPI="ON"
```

and then run the command

```
pip install --no-binary=h5py  h5py
```

which gives me the following output at the end (there is more before the beginning of the following snippet):

```
warning: h5py\api_types_hdf5.pxd:732:6: 'H5Z_ENABLE_EDC' redeclared
    warning: h5py\api_types_hdf5.pxd:733:6: 'H5Z_NO_EDC' redeclared
    building 'h5py.defs' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\bdaniele
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\bdaniele\AppData
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\bdaniele\AppData\Local
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\bdaniele\AppData\Local\Temp
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\bdaniele\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gmwxxuog
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\bdaniele\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gmwxxuog\h5py
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\bdaniele\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gmwxxuog\h5py\h5py
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DH5_USE_16_API -D_HDF5USEDLL_ -DH5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB -I.\h5py -IC:\Users\bdaniele\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gmwxxuog\h5py\lzf -IC:\Users\bdaniele\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gmwxxuog\h5py\windows -IC:\Users\bdaniele\framework\venv\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\bdaniele\framework\venv\Lib\site-packages\mpi4py\include -Ic:\users\bdaniele\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\include -Ic:\users\bdaniele\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /TcC:\Users\bdaniele\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gmwxxuog\h5py\h5py\defs.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\bdaniele\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gmwxxuog\h5py\h5py\defs.obj
    defs.c
    C:\Users\bdaniele\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gmwxxuog\h5py\h5py\defs.c(634): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mpi.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I am able to compile and run programs using the same compiler with parallel tools enabled (MPI, OpenMP) without any problems. The documentation of h5py does not explain how to setup h5py on Windows using Visual Studio.
I don't have admin rights. 
I would like to use this package with the MPI option enabled because I would like to read and write in parallel eventually (example: http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/mpi.html#using-parallel-hdf5-from-h5py), and this feature seems to be installed with h5py.

What can I do to solve this problem?
Thanks!

**Update**:

After adding the paths for the MPI and HDF5 libraries in the `setup_build.py` file I was able to install h5py. However, when I try to run a python script, I get an error when importing h5py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\testparh5.py", line 2, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "C:\Users\bdaniele\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py-2.9.0.post0-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\h5py\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import _errors
  File "MPI.pxd", line 62, in init h5py._errors
ValueError: mpi4py.MPI.Message size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 40 from C header, got 32 from PyObject
```

Is it related to the `mpi4py` or other packages?

Comment: do you really need to build h5py? Those kinds of builds can be very cumbersome in Windows environments. Have you considered Anaconda instead. It ships pre-built binaries for Linux, Osx and Win64 environments.

Comment: I just need to be able to run on Win64 the example I linked in the post.  

On the Anaconda website there are no packages of h5py-parallel for Win64 environment but only for Linux and Osx: (https://anaconda.org/search?q=h5py).

Comment: You're right, MPI is only enabled for Linux and OsX for h5py. You've been able to build tests with MPI on your workstation, so I assume you have a MPI implementation installed. As far as I can see in your log, the header file mpi.h is not found. You may have to specify the directory containing the MPI Headers manually.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant anymore, but I was able to overcome the error that comes on importing h5py by copying all the DLLs in the bin folder of HDF5 install directory to the h5py folder in the h5py-version-arch-etc.egg folder in python site-packages.